# Testing a gSOAP server

Tags: c++, soap, gsoap

In a normal client/server design, the client can execute functions implemented on the server-side. Is it possible to test a gSOAP server by connecting an extra client to it?

Answer (score 1):

I have not used gSOAP, but from reading the documentation it allows you to write both clients and servers so you can write an test client to test the service.

However if you are planning to offer the service to clients written in .net or java I would recommend that you write the test client in one of these.  This way you will know for certain that it is possible to use the service from one of these clients. You might also find that .net or java clients are easier to write if you server is designed in a specific way, your test client will help you find this out.

Comment: I would like to use the same C++ clients that gsoap is generating. But I don't know if I can connect two clients to one server.

Comment: Again I have not used gSOAP but usually webservices can support multiple clients

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is, use [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) to generate client connections and data. Its free.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other comments: testing a gSOAP server can be easily done offline using IO redirect. When you invoke soap_serve() without any sockets set up prior to this call, the server engine will simply accept data from standard input and write data to standard output. This is a great way to hit an offline server implementation hard with XML data patterns for testing before deploying the server online. The gSOAP tool even generates example XML messages that you can use for this purpose.